# How would I insert a download link into image2 or how would I make it into a download button?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the script I am currently working with

The first image(https - in code below) is a countdown giff IT then switches to the second image(https - in code below) after 10seconds

I would make image2(https - In code below) a download button or I would like to add a download link into the image but I am unsure how to

I know how to add it if it wasn't written into this script (below)

But It's left me a little confused on what to do.

Here is the script I am working with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>

<body> <img id="img1" src="IMAGE1.gif" />
  <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("img1").src = "IMAGE2.png";
    }, 10000);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap you image in an `<a>` tag and set its `href` value after your timeout.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("img1").src = "http://via.placeholder.com/200x200";
  document.getElementById("link").href = "https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf";
}, 10000);
```

```html
<a id="link">
  <img id="img1" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50"/>
</a>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. How would I got about inserting that code you just gave me into the script that I am using ?